# TS-2590 error produced by custom chakra-ui component style overrider fn

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I've created a function that works similarly to `@chakra-ui/react`'s `chakra()` factory function, that can overload any property on target component. It works but I can't seem to resolve the TS-2590 union type error it creates.

```
import { As, chakra, ChakraComponent, Stack } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { ComponentProps, ForwardedRef, forwardRef, ForwardRefExoticComponent, PropsWithoutRef } from 'react';

function makeChakra<
  T extends As,
  P = {},
  FP = PropsWithoutRef<ComponentProps<T> & P> ,
  FPR = ForwardRefExoticComponent<FP & ComponentProps<ChakraComponent<T>>>
>(
  comp: T,
  label?: string
): (
  props?: Partial<ComponentProps<ChakraComponent<T>>>
) => FPR {
  const Component = chakra(comp, {
    label,
  });


  // type RT = ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>>;

  return (props = {}) =>
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
    (forwardRef<ChakraComponent<T>, ComponentProps<T>>(
      (
        innerProps: ComponentProps<T>,
        ref: ForwardedRef<ChakraComponent<T>>
      ) => {
  
        return <Component ref={ref} {...props} {...innerProps} />;
      }
    ) as FPR);
}


// HERE

export const CustomStack = makeChakra(
    Stack,
    "CustomStack"
)({
    pos: "relative",
    spacing: 24,
    m: 20,
    placeItems: "stretch",
    placeContent: "stretch",

    lineHeight: "shorter",
});
// =>  Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.nts(2590)
```